# How to avoid appending other "div's" when we reload a particular "div" every x seconds using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am working on a project in which am trying to reload the div every 30 seconds without reloading the whole page -

Below is my div in my JSP file `(dataInfo.jsp)` and I want to reload the div `container` every 30 seconds without reloading the full page.

```
<body>
    <div id='headerDivDash'>
        <h1 id='topHeaderDash'>
          <!-- some image here -->
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="vertical-list" style='display: block; list-style-type: none;'>
        <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
            <a href="_blank"><li>Test 1</li></a>
            <br />
            <a href="_blank"><li>Test 2</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- just need to reload this div, other div should be intact without getting appended -->
    <div class="container">
        <c:forEach var="e" items="${testing.data}">
            <div class="component">
                <h3>
                    For
                    <c:out value="${e.key}" />
                </h3>
                <table id="tabDes" style=''>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Machine Name</th>
                            <th>Fresh 95</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="m" items="${e.value}">
                            <tr>
                                <th>${m.machines}</th>
                                <td class="color-changer">${m.Fresh 95}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Some Value Here</div>
</body>
```

And below is my method in my controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, Mapping> testOperation() {

    final Map<String, Mapping> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, Mapping>();

    // .. some code here

    Mapping mappings = Utils.getData(machines);

    model.put("testing", mappings);
    return model;
}
```

So on the browser, I am hitting - `http://some.host.com:8080/web/testOperation` and then it shows me the actual content from the JSP file on the browser.

Now below is the jquery script I am using to load the `div container` every 30 seconds

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function ()
        {
        $('.container').html('');
        $('.container').load('dataInfo.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
        }, 30 * 1000);

    });
</script>
```

Now the problem that I am facing is if I am reloading the `container` div every 30 seconds, then my header div and footer div, they are getting appended everytime and I am not sure how should I fix this issue? Any thoughts?

My ultimate goal is to load the the `container` div every 30 seconds without reloading the page and without appending any other divs. That's all

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load -- see *"Loading Page Fragments"*

Comment: Aahh.. make sense.. I am not a UI/jquery guy.. So in my case, it will be like this `$('.container').load('dataInfo.jsp #container').fadeIn("slow");` ? Correct?

Comment: `.container`, not `#container` (unless your div also has an `id="container"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yeah because you are getting the whole dataInfo file (header,footer and all) every time.

Separate your files like this:

dataInfo.jsp will contain the header, footer, and container div for the content

```
<body>
<div id='headerDivDash'>
    <h1 id='topHeaderDash'>
      <!-- some image here -->
    </h1>
</div>
<div id="vertical-list" style='display: block; list-style-type: none;'>
    <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
        <a href="_blank"><li>Test 1</li></a>
        <br />
        <a href="_blank"><li>Test 2</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">

</div>
<div class="footer">Some Value Here</div>
</body>
```

then create another file called 'content' or something and put the container markup in it

```
<c:forEach var="e" items="${testing.data}">
        <div class="component">
            <h3>
                For
                <c:out value="${e.key}" />
            </h3>
            <table id="tabDes" style=''>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Machine Name</th>
                        <th>Fresh 95</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach var="m" items="${e.value}">
                        <tr>
                            <th>${m.machines}</th>
                            <td class="color-changer">${m.Fresh 95}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

then in your jquery get the content file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('.container').html('');
    $('.container').load('yourcontentfile').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 30 * 1000);

});
```